# D3.js bar chart to line chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Im trying to build a page that displays a dataset in a line chart, I have the data being presented in a bar chart, but want it to be a line chart with the tool tip on each of the points. does anyone know how I would convert my code from making a bar chart to a line chart. i also need to add a grid to the background of the graph if anyone knows how I would do that using d3.js also wish to have the y axis displayed as a percentage rather than decimals

HTML --

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Demo</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <svg class="chart"></svg>

            <script type="text/javascript"src="js/d3/d3.js"></script>
            
            <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bumbeishvili/d3-tip-for-v6@4/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"src="js/myscript1.js"></script>
        
        </body>
    </html>
```

css --

```
    .bar{fill: steelblue;}

.axis text{font: 10px sans-serif;}
.axis path, .axis line { fill: none; stroke: #000; shape-rendering: crispEdges; }

.x.axis path{display: none;}

.bar:hover {
    fill: orangered ;
  }

.d3-tip {
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  }
  
  /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  /* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
```

js -

```
    var margin = { top: 20 , right: 20, bottom: 30 , left: 40} ,
width= 960 - margin.left - margin.right ,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom )
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate (" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +")") ;

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]) ; //remember: up / down are flipped

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width]).padding([0.1]); //the last peramter adds padding

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(event,d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.csv("data/data.csv").then(function(data) {
    x.domain(data.map(function(d){return d.letter;}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.frequency;})]);
    // Remember to add all data dependant calls in here
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x); // Positions the Lables Under the xAxis

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y); // positions the lables on the left of the yAxis

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x (d.letter);})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return y (d.frequency);})
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) {return height - y (d.frequency);})
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
  
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", (width / 2))
      .attr("y", 0 + (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Relative Frequence of Letters in the English Alphabet") ;
});
```

Comment: The question is very broad, a line chart has many different elements from the bar chart. I advise you to search the web for some simple examples (there are many) and come back with some specific question on some difficulties that you may find on your implementation